# I have a python list as strings and i want to print it out as spaced between and sequential

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a python list and i want to print them in an sequential order and spaced between them

```
x = "hello world"
>>> x[2:10]  # this prints from 'l' to 'd' allway

>>> x[2:10:2]  # this prints from 'l' to 'd' in the order of two,
'lowr'
```

how can i print it like 'l o w r ', putting a space character between them without a loop? So it would look like 'l-o-w-r'

Comment: `'-'.join(s[2:10:2])`

Comment: ' '.join(x[2:10:2])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out Python's [str.join()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) function. It lets you join any iterable whilst inserting whatever you put in between the quotes `""` in `.join()`.

Like so:

```
x = "hello world"

" ".join(x[2:10:2])
```

Answer (score 2):

Just join the characters in the list with a single space, or with a `-`, as you feel like. This uses a [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) which gives you a string stitched together from the elements of the list by the given separator

```
x = "hello world"
print(' '.join(x[2:10:2]))
#l o w r
print('-'.join(x[2:10:2]))
#l-o-w-r
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings have a [`.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method which will join together the elements of that iterable with the string you give in the middle. For example

```py
>>> x = 'hello world'
>>> sep = ' '  # your separator is a space
>>> sep.join(x[2:10:2])
'l o w r'
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by without a loop, but you could do the following:

```py
x = "hello world"
' '.join(y for y in x[2:10:2])
```